# div block containing tabs, and regular div block. Position side by side with space between them

Tags: html, css

I have two div blocks, one with tabs, one regular one. Here is the html:

```
<div id = "container"></div>
<div>
<ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">My Quests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Find</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
           <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
           <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanted to place these side by side, with space between them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPv2I.png
![]dsd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPv2I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float` or `inline-block` for this type of functionality.

css:

```
.tabs, .tab_container{
 float:left;
}
```

may be you have to read these articles also:

http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/

http://css-tricks.com/37-the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Edit:

as per the below comment write this:

```
.tabs, .tab_container{
     display:inline-block;
     white-space:normal;
    }
```

& give `white-space` to its `parent`

```
.parent{white-space:nowrap}
```

Html :

```
<div class="parent">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">My Quests</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Find</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
           <!--Content-->
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
           <!--Content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works! But when resizing the window, I want the tabs container to be fixed...it moves.

Comment: can you explain it a little more what to actual want. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry :p. When I resize the browser window, the "tabs_container" div clears out, I want it to stay fixed and not clear below the "container" div

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `float:left` do the job as sandeep said but be careful of [Float/Margin bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html) in IE6. I know IE6 is almost off the table now, but just in case.